# Wordpress .htaccess 500 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My site is working fine on localhost but when I uploaded on live site, It is giving 500 error on a CSS file

```
wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/templates/style.css
```

While this CSS is working fine

```
wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/custom.css
```

Here is my htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?uploads/wpjobboard/application/(.+) /mysite/wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/restrict.php?url=application/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I am pretty sure that there is some problem in my htaccess because the plugin path is defined in it. Can someone debug my htaccess and tell me the cause?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whatever that restricting-type plugin you're using (restricting users? posts?) ... I'd write that author in the support forum and see what he/she says, or if others are having the same problem.

Comment: Find your Apache error log and look what error is listed in there. An internal server error can be a lot of things.

Comment: @JasonWeber I was 1st checking on my own live site and everything was fine there but when I uploaded files to client's site (other hosting, other domain) it shows 500.

Comment: @Sumurai8 500 error is on every file and folder that exists in
wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/

Comment: However rest of my site is working fine, the 500 error is only on this directory
wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/